# How to inflate setListAdapter into main layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a list of businesses grabbed from a server and display them beneath the search box in a listview.

I am using setListAdapter to call my arrayAdapter class that I send the array to.  When I run the code it creates a new screen with the resuts in. I want the results on the same screen.

Here is my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#FF9900"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="60px" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <RelativeLayout  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/rel1" 
        android:gravity="right">
        <AutoCompleteTextView 
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_classif"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:text="Search" 
            android:onClick="myClickHandler" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/editText2" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:text="" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </EditText>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/mylocation"
        android:lines="1" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </TextView>

<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
    android:visibility="gone"> 
</ProgressBar>

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/pagetext" android:lines="50"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:padding="5px"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the layout I am inflating dynamincally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="10px"
    android:layout_height="140px" android:id="@+id/rlt_main"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="#000000">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/bus_name"
        android:text="Name" ></TextView>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/description" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/bus_name" android:layout_marginLeft="10px"></TextView>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/distance" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/description" android:layout_marginLeft="10px"></TextView>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/longitude" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/distance" android:layout_marginLeft="10px"></TextView>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/iv_forward" android:background="@drawable/forward_arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I collate the data and send it to my class:

```
if(found) {
    jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray  jResult = jArray.getJSONArray("result");

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> varray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    for(int i=0;i < jResult.length();i++){    
        JSONObject e = jResult.getJSONObject(i);

        output.append(e.getString("webid") + "\n");

        output.append(e.getString("webDistance") + "\n");

        String longi = e.getString("webLongtitude");

        String lati = e.getString("webLatitude");
        String geoURI = String.format("geo:%s,%s", lati, longi);   
        output.append(geoURI+"\n");

        output.append("--------------------------------------------\n");
        ArrayList<String> det = new ArrayList<String>();
        det.add(e.getString("webEntryName"));
        det.add(e.getString("webAddress"));
        det.add(e.getString("webDistance"));
        det.add(e.getString("webLongtitude"));
        det.add(e.getString("webLatitude"));
        varray.add(det);

    }

    setListAdapter(new busListAdapter(this, varray ));
}
```

And this is the arrayAdapter class:

```
package com.dentons.dentonsweb;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class busListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> varray;  
    private  ArrayList<String> varray2;

    public busListAdapter(DentonswebActivity context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> varray) {
        super(context, R.layout.business_list_item, varray);
        this.context = context;
        this.varray = varray;
    }



    // static to save the reference to the outer class and to avoid access to
    // any members of the containing class
    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
    }

    @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.business_list_item, parent, false);

            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.bus_name);
            TextView description=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.description);
            TextView distance=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            TextView longitude=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.longitude);

        varray2 = varray.get(position);

        label.setText(varray2.get(0));
        description.setText(varray2.get(1));
        distance.setText(varray2.get(2));
        longitude.setText(varray2.get(3));

        return row;
    }
}
```

If I could find a way of telling the layout to inflate into main that would be great but I don't seem to be able to get a reference to main from within this class.  The best I have managed is for the inflation to happen within first screen but with no result.  I can't remember how I did this.  I am quite new to Java.

---

This is the latest code:

This appear in main.xml

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/pagetext" android:lines="50"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:padding="5px"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</TextView>
```

This is the new busListAdapter:

```
package com.dentons.dentonsweb;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class busListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> varray;  
    private  ArrayList<String> varray2;

    public busListAdapter(DentonswebActivity context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> varray) {
        super(context, R.layout.business_list_item, varray);
        this.context = context;
        this.varray = varray;
    }



    // static to save the reference to the outer class and to avoid access to
    // any members of the containing class
    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
    }

    @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.business_list_item, parent, false);

            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.bus_name);
            TextView description=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.description);
            TextView distance=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            TextView longitude=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.longitude);

        varray2 = varray.get(position);

        label.setText(varray2.get(0));
        description.setText(varray2.get(1));
        distance.setText(varray2.get(2));
        longitude.setText(varray2.get(3));

        return row;
    }
}
```

This is the calling code:

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.viewStub1);
stub.inflate();

setListAdapter(new busListAdapter(this, varray ));
```

Any ideas why this is still opening on a blank page.

Comment: Can you post the code that inflates your listview? In any case, you can use a ViewStub in your main layout and inflate that.

Comment: @Jave - It's just this line: setListAdapter(new busListAdapter(this, varray ));

Comment: so you are using a ListActivity then?

Comment: Ah, sorry yes, it was originally listview but I thought it was a type of listview.  So, how do I use this ViewStub?  I am going to go do some research now but just wondered if you could give me an example.  really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can start by taking a look at this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html  
  
I'll see if I can get an example up by tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks I have had a look at that but am still a bit confused how to incorporate this.

Comment: Ah sorry for not getting back to you, I got a bit tied up and forgot about it, posted an answer with some information for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) to create your layout. You put your ViewStub in the main layout where you want your layout to be inflated, and set the parameters as you want them to be.
Example:

```
 <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub"
           android:inflatedId="@+id/newId"
           android:layout="@layout/layoutName"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="140dp" />
```

This will be inflated to the layout defined in layout/layoutName.xml.
When you want to inflate the view you would find the stub and then call its [`inflate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html#inflate%28%29) method:

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
stub.inflate();
```

Now the new layout is where the stub previously was, and you can find your list and set the adapter on it:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listId);
list.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

**Note:** it is not necessary to use the ViewStub to create a list, it is simply used here as your original question related to *inflating* a list view, although the problem you describe are because you use a ListActivity instead of an Activity (See below).

You should also change your activity to a normal [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) instead of a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) (or change your layout according to the [documentation guidelines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)) as the ListActivity is designed to have a list as the only display element, and that is why your custom layout is replaced with the list now.

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

I hope this clears up some things.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a go when I get time again.  The only thing that concerns me is passing a multi dimension array to the listview.

Comment: You are welcome, and your adapter seems to be able to handle the mutli-dimension array, so that shouldn't cause any trouble.

Comment: I have tried this and it still open up on a blank screen. See code below:

Comment: See new code in original question for new problematic code.  Thanks.

Comment: You still call setListAdapter() on the activity itself, and not your listview... If you have a ListView, get it with findViewById(), and then on that listview call setAdapter().

Comment: Sorry I'm just not grasping this.  I have used setListAdapter(new busListAdapter(this, varray )); which writes to the layout business_list_item.xml  Before this I used ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.viewStub1); stub.inflate(); viewStub1 references android:layout="@layout/business_list_item"

Comment: The stub is, as noted in my answer not necessary for a list, it is a way to inflate a view, as your title asks for "How to inflate setListAdapter into main layout?". However, what you want to do seems inconsistent with that. So here is what you should do: make your activity extend Activity, not ListActivity.  In your main layout xml, you put a ListView. In your code, you do `Listview list = (ListView) findViewById(listid);`  
`list.setAdapter(new busListAdapter(this, varray));`

Comment: OK, it's not crashing now. It doesn't seem to be displaying anything though. `ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1); list.setAdapter(new busListAdapterTest(this ));` Listview is `<ListView
 android:id="@+android:id/list1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:background="#CCCCCC"
 android:padding="5px"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"> >
</ListView>`  As an extra test I changed the Adapter to just fill each field with the text "test" which is why I no longer pass the varray array.

Comment: Change your list id from "@+android:id/list1" to "@+id/list1" "@+android" does not work.

Comment: Still getting the same thing. `<ListView
 android:id="@+id/list1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:background="#CCCCCC"
 android:padding="5px"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"> >
</ListView>`

Comment: if you no longer pass the varray, how does you adapter know how many items to display? If you end up with an empty list in the adapter, it will draw 0 elements.

Comment: Yeah I just realised it wasn't a good test.  I used the busListAdapter class successfully with no problems using just setListAdapter so it's not that.  I just used Toast to make sure I was returning array items which I am.  I'm not getting any errors so I'm pretty stumped.  Do you have a working version of this?  I can provide the whole source code as a download if you think it will help.  Thank you so much for you help and your patience.

Comment: If you can upload your source to pastebin or similiar, I can have a look at it if you want..

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it working by putting the listview above a progressbar and a textview.  Thank you very much for you help.  We got there eventually. :)

Comment: Strange solution, there must have been some sort of id collision or something? Anyways, good job, and hopefully we learnt something from all of this :P